# image not loading in php

Tags: php, database, rows

[enter link description here][1]
i have table events in my database with information of all different events

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `descrption` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `organizer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price_of_tickets` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_tickets` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `services` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

now i want a single row  to be fetched from database when user clicks a event page
and same way if user clicks some other event a different row must be fetched 
i tried doing it by taking the id of table but couldn't succeed

```
<div class="blog-page">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 

          <!--Blog Block Start-->
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
            <div class="blog-details blog-post">
              <div class="featured-img">
                <div class="event-counter"></div>
                <img src="images/ef-1.jpg" alt=""> </div>
              <div class="blog-details-text">

              <div class="post-title"> <span class="post-date"> <?php echo $row['2'] ?></strong> </span>
                  <h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a></h5>
                </div>

              <ul class="post-meta">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $row['organizer'] ?></a></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"><?php echo $row['category'] ?></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> 206 Comments</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 240 Likes</a></li>
                </ul>


              <?php echo $row['descrption'] ?>

                <blockquote>
                  <p>The gloves were commonly used by health care workers in the United States but can harm both patients and doctors. The use of powdered latex gloves is already falling. According to the FDA, right now only six registered manufacturers of powdered latex gloves are left in the U.S.</p>
                  <a class="authorOrTitle" href="#"><span>―</span> Peter Hakim, president emeritus at the Inter-American Dialogue</a> </blockquote>
                <p>More this in this sensational after by woolly jeez while globefish incessantly vulture overpaid hare tidy fumbling after far dramatic that surely aside one much ferret wolf at sheep one as some yikes onto one while yikes spoiled one unskillfully magically wow frugal as handsomely contrite popularly laboriously possessively querulously misheard activated goodness honey wow less due and distant that expedient therefore and raffish devotedly.</p>
                <p>Yikes decided grizzly where slept jeez spread this after that chameleon unreceptive one ferociously in dear hooted more cheerfully yikes ocelot behind a alas slung bid jeepers cracked grumbled goodness cardinally far whispered this that wombat leopard soothing one much one the in salamander versus cowered some far rebuilt banefully on.</p>
                <h6>More this in this sensational after.</h6>
                <figure class="alignleft"> <img src="images/bd2.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
                  <figcaption>The gloves were commonly used by health. <a href="#">― Photo By Eric Knowles</a> </figcaption>
                </figure>
                <p>More this in this sensational after by woolly jeez while globefish incessantly vulture overpaid hare tidy fumbling after far dramatic that surely aside one much ferret wolf at sheep one as some yikes onto one while yikes spoiled one unskillfully magically wow frugal as handsomely contrite popularly laboriously possessively querulously misheard activated goodness honey wow less due and distant that expedient therefore and raffish devotedly.</p>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the ID to your query condition:

```
$query= "select * from event where id = {$r}; ";
```

Comment: will this do the rquired task n how do i need to fetch these values in php file

Comment: I don't unterstand your question.

Comment: how should i refernce the variables to fetch the values from the database

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment right now, but if I understood your last comment you want to fetch all data where id = ?. So you need the query from the first answer and after executing it you store the result in a variable. To fetch all the data, you could use a `while` loop where you say: (example)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $name = $row["eventName"] // this depends on your column in your database. For example if you have an event name and your column name is: eventName , this is how you fetch your results from query
}
```

**Note** I recommend using PDO. Here is a good starting [tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query)

**THIS IS AN EDIT!**

So, say you create a new file named: `fetch.php`, and you have this function in the file:

```
<?php

function fetchData($id)
{
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "events") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   $query= "select * from event where id = {$id}; "; 
   $query_result=mysqli_query($conn ,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)) {
      $result = $row["eventName"];
   }

   return $result;
}
```

And now, in your pages files, for example page 1 file: `page1.php` you make this:

```
include 'fetch.php';
$id = 1; //or some other number, depending on your page (if I understood you right)
$result = fetchData($id);
echo $result;
```

I hope that this is the answer you need, good luck :)

**A NEW EDIT:**
Try it with this [link](https://pastebin.com/H1sgJTsj). It has code for 2 files.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167962/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-danoski-image-not-loading-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
<?php

if (!filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'id')) {
    // handle error ...
}

$eventId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:dbname=tests;host=127.0.0.1',
    'username',
    'password',
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ]
);
$preparedSelect = $pdo->prepare(
    'select *
     from event
     where id = :id
     limit 1'
);
$preparedSelect->execute(['id' => $eventId]);
$event = $preparedSelect->fetchObject();
if (!$event) {
    // handle error ...
}
echo htmlspecialchars($event->title);
?>

<a href="?id=1">Click</a>
```

Take a look at these:

- https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

**ADDED:**

```
<?php
/*
This takes a value from the URL.
For instance, if you go to the page with something like that:
http://yourdomain.com/the/path/?id=45487
It will take the value 45487. That's the event id that you're 
trying to access.
Of course I don't know what's the URL you're using.
I made up the "http://yourdomain.com/the/path/" and you need to 
replace it. The important part is the "?id=45487"
*/
if (!filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'id')) {
    echo "Event id is missing!";
    die;
}
$eventId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

/*
I'm using PDO to access the database.
Of course, I don't know what's your database name and server host.
You need to replace the "tests" and "localhost" accordingly.
I also don't know what's the username and password you're using.
You need to replace them.
*/
$pdo = new PDO(
    // replace the database name
    'mysql:dbname=tests;host=localhost',
    // replace the username
    'username',
    // replace the password
    'password',
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ]
);
// This is a prepared statement
$preparedSelect = $pdo->prepare(
    'select *
     from event
     where id = :id
     limit 1'
);
// I'm making a query here
$preparedSelect->execute(['id' => $eventId]);
/*
I'm fetching the event as an object.
That means that you'd access the values like this:
$event->title
If you want to use associative arrays instead, do this:
$event = $preparedSelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
*/
$event = $preparedSelect->fetchObject();
if (!$event) {
    echo "Event #$eventId was not found!";
    die;
}
?>

<div class="blog-page">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 

          <!--Blog Block Start-->
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
            <div class="blog-details blog-post">
              <div class="featured-img">
                <div class="event-counter"></div>
                <img src="images/ef-1.jpg" alt=""> </div>
              <div class="blog-details-text">

              <div class="post-title"> <span class="post-date"></strong> </span>
                  <h5><a href="#"><?= htmlspecialchars($event->title) ?></a></h5>
              </div>

              <ul class="post-meta">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"><?= htmlspecialchars($event->organizer) ?></a></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"><?= htmlspecialchars($event->category) ?></a></li>

                <?= $event->descrption ?>
```

Don't forget to read the pages that I referenced.

Comment: how should i implement it

Comment: Did you have a look at the pages I told you to have a look?
They explain how to use PDO to access the database and pass values when submitting forms or links.

If you know the basics of PHP, you can adapt the code that I provided, replacing the PDO construction arguments, removing the "echo" and HTML code and using your HTML code but with the $event object.